# $match a $lookup if pubDate

Tags: mongodb, lookup

I am trying to only return episodes that have been released less than todays date.
As we have podcast episodes that we don't release until future dates but they are already in the DB.

What I have tried

```
[{$match: {
  'active': true,
  'station': {
    $all: ['DRN1']
  }
}}, {$lookup: {
  'from': 'episode',
  'localField': 'url',
  'foreignField': 'show_b',
   pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              "episode.pubDate":{$lte:new Date()}
          }

      }
  ],
  'as': 'match_docs'
}}, {$project: {
  'id': 1,
  'title': 1,
  'icon': 1,
  'banner': 1,
  'url': 1,
  'last': {
    '$slice': ['$match_docs.pubDate',-1]
  },
  'latestepisode': {
    '$slice': ['$match_docs', -1]
  }
}}, {$sort: {
  'last': -1
}}]
```

the issue is the pipeline.
error I am getting is

> $lookup with 'pipeline' may not specify 'localField' or 'foreignField'

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve the issue by doing this, I know their is a better way so looking forward to other answers.

```
[{$match: {
  'active': true,
  'station': {
    $all: ['DRN1']
  }
}}, {$lookup: {
  'from': 'episode',
  'localField': 'url',
  'foreignField': 'show_b',
  'as': 'match_docs'
}}, {$project: {
  'id': 1,
  'title': 1,
  'icon': 1,
  'banner': 1,
  'url': 1,
  'match_docs':{
    '$filter':{
      "input" : "$match_docs",
                     "as" : "item",
                     "cond" : { "$lte" : ["$$item.pubDate",new Date()]}
    }
  },
  'last': {

          '$slice': ['$match_docs.pubDate',-1]
  },
  'latestepisode': {
    '$slice': ['$match_docs', -1]
  }
}}, {$project: {
  'id': 1,
  'title': 1,
  'icon': 1,
  'banner': 1,
  'url': 1,
  'last': {
    '$slice': ['$match_docs.pubDate',-1]
  },
  'latestepisode': {
    '$slice': ['$match_docs', -1]
  }
}}, {$sort: {
  'last': -1
}}]
```